# How do I create a new file from message queue?

Tags: vb.net, file, message-queue, filestream, send

Now I can send a file to message queue but I don't know how to create a new file from message queue with another PC. I send file from one PC to another PC through message queue. This is my code.

```
Dim backupDir As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\testProgram\testProgramout.txt"

Dim fileStr As FileStream = New FileStream(backupDir, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)
fileStr.Close()
Dim sw As New StreamWriter(backupDir, True, Encoding.ASCII)
Dim NextLine As MemoryStream = mq.Peek.BodyStream
sw.Write(NextLine)
sw.Close()
```

But this code is return this sentence "System.IO.MemoryStream". It's not return the data in file. So I'tried to change the path at backupDir = myqueue.path but the given path's format is not supported.

Comment: You cannot write an entire `MemoryStream` directly to a `StreamWriter`. It handles it as a generic object and calls its `ToString()` method, which is returning its type name. If you want to write the contents of a message either use the [`Body` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.message.body?view=netframework-4.8) to get the contents directly, or use a `StreamReader` to read the data from `BodyStream` and then write it to the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: how to set path from message queue in streamReader, I set like this 
Dim sw As StreamReader = File.OpenText(myqueue.Path)
but it's error "The given path's format is not supported."

Comment: You don't need a path. `StreamReader`s [take streams as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_): `Dim sr As New StreamReader(mq.Peek().BodyStream)`